# Ninject - what kind of design pattern is it considered to be?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ninject

I've started to learn about IOC and specifically Ninject.

I was wondering what kind of design pattern does Ninject falls in to? It seems to me like a Factory design pattern, because I basically define a set of rules, create a kernel in my code and as that kernel for my object - which is like having a Factory and ask it for an object of a type which matches what I am sending to it.

Am I right about this? or is this a whole different category?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all, Ninject follows the Dependency Injection pattern.
You can find out more about it here: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

This pattern encourages the Dependency Inversion principle, which states that you should depend upon abstractions, instead of concretions. These two concepts are often mistaken for each other.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. I interpreted the question as "what patterns are used to implement this framework" rather than "what patterns can be applied with this framework". But the latter question is much harder to answer, because it will internally use many design patterns (although DI itself is not used much internally).

Comment: I interpreted it as "what pattern does this framework implement [for me]"? And "Dependency Injection" is my answer. The paragraph about the Dependency Inversion principle was more like a bonus, I was trying to help illustrate its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inversion of control
2. Dependency Injection

And, if properly used, **Composition Root**, but yes this is not only ninject is always part of the solution in order to properly set up any container.

Answer (score 1):

It follows Dependency Injection(DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC)
learn more about it on their website's wiki:
http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html

They give a nice and simple example with ninjas and swords!